Как записать в yaml в переменную значение из файла?
У меня есть файл values.yaml
В нем
extraSecretEnv: 
  SECRET_KEY: 'Password'

Нужно, чтобы данный пароль был в секрете, а не в Git.
Я закинул значение 'Password' в секрет в K8S, смотировал секрет в файл app/secretkey
Когда я пробую написать так:
extraSecretEnv: 
  SECRET_KEY: 'app/secretkey'

Он логично сохраняет в переменную данный путь, а не значение. Как именно значение из файла закинуть в переменную в YAML ?

Разобрался сам. Без монтирования, через секреты. Добавил локальный секрет secretkey, значение cекрета добавил в key c с таким же название secretkey:
extraSecretEnv: 
  - name: SECRET_KEY
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: secretkey
        key: secretkey

